# Sending data to a given communicator

Tags: mpi

I wonder if it is possible to send data to a 3rd party communicator by having its integer value.
In other words, I would like to send a MPI_Comm (int) to processes in a non-related communicator in order to establish a communication between them.

For example, this picture shows my goal:
[image: Communicators scheme]

For this purpose, I have developed testing codes which intend to transfer the MPI_Comm.

> parent.c

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    int world_size, world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    MPI_Comm children;
    int err[world_size], msg;

    MPI_Comm_spawn("./children", NULL, 2, MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &children, err);
    if (world_rank == 0) {
        MPI_Send(&children, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, children);
        MPI_Recv(&msg, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, children, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return (0);
}
```

> children.c

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    int world_size, world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
    MPI_Comm parent;
    MPI_Comm_get_parent(&parent);

    int comm, msg = 123;
    if (world_rank == 0) {
        MPI_Recv(&comm, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, parent, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        MPI_Comm children = (MPI_Comm) comm;
        MPI_Send(&msg, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, children);
    }
    MPI_Finalize();
    return (0);
}
```

Of course, the code does not work due to:

> Fatal error in MPI_Send: Invalid communicator, error stack

Is there any way two establish that connection?

PS: This is an example, and I know that if I used "parent" comm in the send  of "children.c", it would work. But my intention is to send data to a 3rd party communicator with only its integer id.

Comment: Communicator handles are local values. You cannot simply send the handle to a process, which is not part of that communicator, and let it communicate. In your case, you might be able to merge "Parent" with "Aux" using `MPI_Intercomm_merge`, then create an intracommunicator between "Children" and the merged "Parent-Aux" using `MPI_Intercomm_create`. Depending on how you perform the merge, the ranks from "Aux" will be either the first ones or the last ones in "Parent-Aux".